SQL - Is it possible to exclude columns from concatenation if NULL?
I have addresses in 5 columns:
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
AddressLine3
AddressLine4
Country
I would like to concatenate these into one column with a comma separating each address line. If the addressline is NULL, then I'd like to not include it, as using a function like IFNULL(AddressLine1,'') will result in 2 commas, one after the other which is what I want to avoid.
Is it possible to exclude NULL to avoid this? Obviously depending on the address either all columns can be populated or only some e.g AddressLine1,AddressLine3,County for each with AddressLine2 and AddressLine4 being NULL
Using ISNULL to return an entry string will result in consecutive commas

Maybe look into using a case statement

Perform a replace after concat to replace ,,  or ,,,  with a single ,

Which dbms are you using?

NULL values are invisible in the concat result. So do something like this.
select concat(address1+', ', address2+', ', address3+', ', country) as Address
from addresses

If you also have empty string values then you should convert them into NULLs. Something like this.
select concat(nullif(address1,'')+', ', nullif(address2,'')+', '....

It works fine on MS SQL Server starting 2008 or earlier.

Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for.

Thanks everyone for your suggestion, Alex's solution is the best one for my situation, cheers

@Denzo37 I would prefer concat_ws() if it is supported by your dbms

Sorry  I should have mentioned, I'm on MSQL server 2012. Thanks for your reply

Depending on dbms used, concat_ws() might be what you want:
concat_ws(',', AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, AddressLine4, Country)

(SQL Server, MariaDB, and perhaps MySQL support this.)

MySQL does support concat_ws() , and it excludes null values. If the separator is null then the result of the string will be null. I guess this info needs to be added to the answer to make it more complete.
